# Missing font character like reduced Planck constant

Tags: android, unicode, fonts, physics

I want to display two Unicode characters in TextView, but I get squares:
 - ℏ (reduced Planck constant/PLANCK CONSTANT OVER TWO PI http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/210f/index.htm)
 - ℞ (PRESCRIPTION TAKE http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/211e/index.htm)

I know that not all Unicode characters are supported by default Android font, but reduced "h-bar" is Latin character and it's one of the fundamental physical constants. Can anyone confirm that I making everything right? And if, how to solve this problem (third-part font is the only solution)?

```
view = new TextView(this);
int[] codePoint = { 0x210f, 0x211e };
String hhh = new String(codePoint, 0, codePoint.length);
view.setText(hhh);
```

Comment: I try to be non-sarcastic here: It's great that we can finally nag about Unicode and font rendering on such a high level ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [character set page](http://www.ascendercorp.com/pdf/Droid_fonts.pdf) the Droid fonts don't support U+210F (ℏ), but they do support U+0127 (ħ), so you might consider using an italic font and U+0127 instead.

Comment: Thanks, it's good tip, at least for "h-bar". I see in this document that droid fonts are on Apache license, and because I only need tow characters, I probably make my own font by drawing and adding missing signs.

Comment: Can you make a custom font with *only* the two missing characters, and have your textview "fail over" to a default system font for everything else?

Answer (score 0):

add font containing characters to /system/fonts,
modify /system/etc/fallback_fonts.xml so android finds font then
reboot.
Everything should be working now

Comment: Can this be done on an unrooted phone?  More importantly, I don't see how this is very practical for an app developer.  Are we to tell our users to make these changes to their systems just to run our apps?